# debug and breakpoint print parameters as alert in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[image]I have an pipeline where i am calling other pipeline.
I want to see the values passed and the action happening when i debug.
In the below, during debug, i want to see what is the value sent with breakpoints for each flow of parameters and also want to see the PL_Purge Folder in action with debug

[!PIPELINE PURGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIla1.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIla1.png)

How to do it,. can you share some links

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the only option to use the set variable activity and assign the value `@item().XXXX` . When you do that & run the pipeline you will be able to values at the pipeline output tab , nothing like a break point in a IDE , but since you have only 4 inputs which you are tracking this should be doable .
Please do let me know how it goes .